# Photoshop in Ubuntu - what are my options?

Tags: virtualization, photoshop

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I tried installing Wine and running CS6 under that but I kept getting the pointer bug where it registers the click but doesn't register the stroke.

I am looking into VirtualBox + Windows options but can't find my XP CD that I bought years ago. Is there a trimmed down version of Windows I could use or something like that? I'd like to stay away from Pirate Bay and downloading illegal copies of Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use GIMP? It's equally feature packed

Comment: Please check this link: http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/complete-guide-to-running-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: Ritik - it's not equally feature packed. I am a pro user and need a lot of the advanced PS features that GIMP doesn't have. 

Saji89 thank you for the link I will look into it.

Comment: Saji89 - does this link fix the pointer bug I mentioned above?

Comment: @Ritik Well, TBH, GIMP has always had that "Vista effect" on me. Though I've had Windows experience since Win 3.11 FW, I had to continuously search for stuff in V. because nearly everything was elsewhere. -- In comparison, GIMP is quite the same: GIMP feels like the Vista among the photo-editing programs, as it has an unique concept which you have to learn separately, without being able to make use of the routine you may have gained from long-time use of Paint Shop Pro and many others. However, come to think of it, Corel Draw was equally a nightmare in handling for me.

Comment: It is not the same as the native experience in windows, but because GIMP is very different from Photoshop, I installed a VirtualBox with a Windows machine, and enjoying Photoshop quite respectfully.

Answer (score 2):

Check the HP from Wine:
[Wine Adobe Photoshop](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17)

Many People tried to use CS2 because there is a official free download version on the hp from adobe. (Tricky to find) The only acceptable Version that works is 7.0

Comment: CS2 and CS3 don't seem to have any major glitches as well, have you tried using them?

Comment: It is on my to do list. Last reviews about Wine+CS2 are over 12 months old, and "silver" -rating is not an acceptable status (for me) btw. i tried CS5 and it crashes from the beginning, every older version then CS5 is not better as a new version of gimp.

Comment: The main reason why I don't use Gimp is that it doesn't handle .psd files correctly and that for me is unacceptable when I receive a .psd from a client. 

I think CS4 has the adjustment layers which Gimp still doesn't have.

Comment: could this be useful: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-best-ways-to-open-a-psd-file-without-photoshop/

Comment: Hm, that depends how good Paint.NET is, as the other options aren't that useful.

Comment: If you haven't already tried, you may want to play with PlayOnLinux (http://www.playonlinux.com/) as a means of installing Photoshop. This has worked well for me. Also if this is super important business wise, you may want to consider Crossover as you can get support from them: http://www.codeweavers.com/

Comment: Kendor - which Photoshop version are you running through Play On Linux? Can you describe your setup in detail?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an **alternative program** like **GIMP**. GIMP is usually packaged with Ubuntu full. GIMP does take some getting used to. For features that GIMP lacks, I'm pretty sure you could find **extensions** for it that does what you want it to do.

Try running it on **Crossover**, which is basically Wine but proprietary.

And then there's always VMs. Boot up a Windows VM and do what you need to do. But then, you aren't exactly running Photoshop on Ubuntu. But then again, you can get your work done fast enough.

I don't know if there is a lite version for Windows (except the ones that are put out by modders) but you can get Windows 10 Home for free from Microsoft's Official site if you can get access to some Windows machine using the [**Media Creation Tool**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). You can read more about how to create installation media for another computer on there. You won't be asked for an activation key. It'll have that Activation watermark and there are some restrictions on customizing your desktop, but if you are running it under a VM, I don't think that's going to be a problem. You'll get the "Your Windows is expiring" popups often enough, but they are just annoying at most and do nothing.